# Select min and max with count

Tags: sql

I have a table called 'Medical Report'
I need to select min date,max date in prescriptionwritten and corresponding active status for particular account number,code

```
Accountnumber code   prescriptionwritten.  Active      
101            201          2019-10-21         0          
101            201          2020-03-24         0     
101            201          2020-05-25         1     
101            202          2019-10-21         0     
101            202          2020-06-20         1
```

Please help with sql query.

The output:

```
101 201 2019-10-21 0  
101 201 2020-05-25 1  
101 202 2019-10-21 0  
101 202 2020-06-20 1
```

Comment: Please provice your expected output int table format

Comment: Something like `select accountnumber,code,max(presriptionwritten),active from table group by accountnumber,code,active`.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using `row_number()`

```
select * from
(
select *,row_number() over(partition by code order by prescriptionwritten) as minrn,
row_number() over(partition by code order by prescriptionwritten desc) as maxrn
from tablename
)A where minrn=1 or maxrn=1
```

Comment: --thanks. Is it possible to get count like how many active, how many inactive between min date, max date?